# Reading bad csv files with garbage values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tokenize, parse-error

I wish to read a csv file which has the following format using pandas:

```
    atrrth
    sfkjbgksjg
    airuqghlerig
    Name         Roll
    airuqgorqowi
    awlrkgjabgwl
    AAA          67
    BBB          55
    CCC          07
```

As you can see, if I use `pd.read_csv`, I get the fairly obvious error:

```
 ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 2
```

But I wish to get the entire data into a dataframe. Using `error_bad_lines = False` will remove the important stuff and leave only the garbage values

These are the 2 of the possible column names as given below :

```
Name : [Name , NAME , Name of student] 
Roll : [Rollno , Roll , ROLL]
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Does you column name remains same or they also change with .csv files?

Comment: No. It doesnt. There is a list of possible names for these columns

Comment: Can you edit your question and give those lists of column names

Comment: [[Name : Name , NAME , Name of student] , [Roll : Rollno , Roll , ROLL]]

Comment: I'll edit the question too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the csv file and find a row from where the column name starts:

```
with open(r'data.csv') as fp:
    skip = next(filter(
        lambda x: x[1].startswith(('Name','NAME')),
        enumerate(fp)
    ))[0]
```

The value will be stored in `skip` parameter

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skiprows=skip)
```

Works in Python 3.X

Comment: The data is in a csv file. How do I get it all into the string "s". I have only given an example here. My data is actually big and I can't manually create "s"

Comment: I wish to generalise this. The garbage values in the very beginning maybe for 3 lines, or 10 lines.

Comment: Is there a way to get hold of all the data irrespective of whether it is "good" or "bad"? The dataframe can be manipulated later

Comment: This will work...upvote and accept if this works for you

Comment: Sorry to deselct your answer but in light of the new edits, can you tell me how the new code should look like? I am not very fluent with reading of files...sorry about this

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest a slight modification/simplification to [@RahulAgarwal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53913391/2988730). Rather than closing and re-opening the file, you can continue loading the same stream directly into pandas. Instead of recording the number of rows to skip, you can record the header line and split it manually to provide the column names:

```
with open(r'data.csv') as fp:
    names = next(line for line in fp if line.casefold().lstrip().startswith('name'))
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, names=names.strip().split())
```

This has an advantage for files with large numbers of trash lines.

A more detailed check could be something like this:

```
def isheader(line):
    items = line.strip().split()
    if len(items) != 2:
        return False
    items = sorted(map(str.casefold, items))
    return items[0].startswith('name') and items[1].startswith('roll')
```

This function will handle all your possibilities, in any order, but also currently skip trash lines with spaces in them. You would use it as a filter:

```
names = next(line for line in fp if isheader(line))
```

Comment: This seems to be a great answer. But my dataset may contain any number of columns. Can you try to look at the new question??

Comment: @Siddharth. You really shouldn't change the requirements in your question once you've received good answers, much less accepted one. Ask a new question instead, and notify the answerers in case they're interested. SO is not a help forum. It's a Q&A site where future readers can get answers to similar problems.

Comment: I understand. Kinda desperate here so went off on an editing spree. In any case, here is the new question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53914354/reading-csv-files-containing-rogue-elements-and-junk-data

I hope you would consider looking at the new question, free from further changes.

Comment: @Siddharth. No problem. I'll be happy to take a look. Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 0):

If that's indeed the structure (and not just an example of what sort of garbage one can get), you can simply use [skiprows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) argument to indicate how many lines should be skipped. In other words, you should read your dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your.csv', skiprows=3)
```

Mind that `skiprows` can do much more. Check the docs.