# How to read excel data from row other than 0?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, analysis

I have an excel files and the first two rows are:
Weekly Report
December 1-7, 2014

And after that comes the relevant table.

When I use 
    filename = r'excel.xlsx'
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    print(df)

I get

```
      Weekly Report        Unnamed: 1                  Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 
3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5
0    December 1-7, 2014               NaN                         NaN        
NaN        NaN        NaN
1                   NaN               NaN                         NaN        
NaN        NaN        NaN
2                  Date               App                    Campaign    
Country       Cost   Installs
```

What I mean is that the columns name is unnamed because it is in the first irrelevant row.

If pandas would read only the table my columns will be installs, cost etc... which I want.

How can I tell him to read starting from line 3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading bad csv files with garbage values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913348/reading-bad-csv-files-with-garbage-values)

Answer (score 1):

Use `skiprows` to your advantage -

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, skiprows=[0,1])
```

This should do it. `pandas` ignores the first two rows in this case -

> skiprows : list-like
>
> Rows to skip at the beginning (0-indexed)

More details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)